# Is it possible to establish a synchronous lunar orbit without using Lagrange points?

Tags: the-moon, orbit

I find this interesting, and so far haven't found anything in an internet search.

Comment: Do you think on some powered trajectory?

Comment: Synchronous with what? A point on the lunar surface? A point on Earth?

Comment: Can you explain carefully what you mean by "synchronous"? Please edit such an explanation into the question. Otherwise it is not really possible to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question on Astronomy.Stackexchange:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20499/is-it-possible-to-achieve-a-stable-lunarstationary-orbit-around-the-moon

Comment: This question is **perfectly clear** and there is no reason to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @SteveLinton "synchronous lunar" ↔ "lunar-synchronous" ↔ "lunasynchronous" ↔ "geosynchronous lunar orbit" ↔ GLEO?

Comment: @uhoh so an orbit which remains above a fixed point on the Moon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Moon’s rotational period is the same as its orbital period: the points on its surface are (approximately) always in the same relationship to Earth. Because of this it is convenient to switch to a frame that rotates with the Earth-Moon system.

Then we're in luck, because now the problem has already been exhaustively explored for us!

[Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) found the collinear stationary points L₁ through L₃ and [Joseph-Louis Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange) added the triangular stationary point L₄ and L₅ thereby completing the picture and showing mathematically that these are the *only five stationary points* in a CR3BP  or circular restricted three-body problem. This was briefly [mentioned elsewhere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20502/7982) as well.

So in a word, no.

> For a tidally locked body there are not going to be any points stationary to the surface other than Lagrange points.

If the Moon was spinning (much) faster (i.e. a long time ago), then a stable synchronous orbit may have been possible. But I’m not sure it was ever spinning that fast.

Comment: The Moon was indeed spinning faster long ago, but it could have been tidally locked to a faster rotating Earth.  Looks like we are going to have to use Lagrange points through time as well as space.

Comment: The Moon was spinning much faster than it is now a long time ago, but it was also a lot closer to the Earth back then. From everything I've read, the Moon became tidally locked very, very early. If the giant impact hypothesis is at all correct, the Moon formed less than 6 Earth radii from the center of the Earth. This would have made tidal forces on the Moon then over a thousand times stronger than they are now, which in turn would made the tidal locking time very, very short. The Moon has been tidally locked for 4.5 billion years.